# php reg exp to check for telephone number

Tags: php, regex

I need a reg exp to check for telephone number, the telephone number goes like this:

```
400-1889-8989
```

So the telephone number should include 0-9 and dash(-) only, and it has to start and end with number. Don't know how to write a reg exp... any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a strict interpretation of your requirements (include 0-9 and dash (-) only, and it has to start and end with number):

```
/^[0-9][0-9-]*[0-9]$/
```

Do realize that this leaves the door open to a variety of inputs that will not even remotely resemble a phone number, e.g. `00`, `0-----9`, `666666666666666666666666` and so on.

Comment: It works with: "80981321-3131" and 8032131-211211-212121

Comment: @Zerquix18 Have I not sufficiently pointed that out in my answer? I start by saying that I follow a strict interpretation of OP's requirements, and in the second part I say that the requirements leave the door open for a lot of inputs not resembling phone numbers. Why do you need to downvote?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sorry, I didn't want you to get angry. I voted up.

Answer (score 1):

This regex will only return true if the number is like "3-4-4", I mean "932-3434-4232" or "534-3342-4233"

```
^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$
```

Comment: No need to escape the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Going by the thought that all telephone numbers would be of the form 000-0000-0000, that is 3 digits followed by `-`, followed by 4 digits, then a `-` again and another 4 digits.

The regex will be like this

```
/[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}/
```